# Can't get HTTPS working in Spring Boot (PKCS12 not found)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I've been attempting to follow the following tutorials regarding setting up HTTPS in Spring Boot:

- https://www.drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/
- https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/

But when I start up my app in Eclipse it throws an exception:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to load keystore type [PKCS12 ]
>   with path
>   [file:/C:/Users/dbush/workspace/my_app/target/classes/keystore.p12]
>   due to [PKCS12  not found]

I checked the filename given and the file exists.  I also ran `keytool -list -keystore keystore.p12` and was able to read it after giving the password used to create it, which is the same password in application.properties.

Any idea what could be causing this?

I also tried using a JKS file instead of a PKCS12 file and got the same error with "JKS not found".

My pom.xml contains:

```xml
...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId> org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
..
```

My main App.java:

```
package dbush;

import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityCollection;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityConstraint;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "dbush.repository")
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
      TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
          @Override
          protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
            securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
            SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
            collection.addPattern("/*");
            securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
            context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
          }
        };

      tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
      return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector redirectConnector() {
      Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
      connector.setScheme("http");
      connector.setPort(8080);
      connector.setSecure(false);
      connector.setRedirectPort(8443);

      return connector;
    }    

}
```

My application.properties:

```properties
security.require_ssl=true

server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
server.ssl.key-password=changeit
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
```

Full stack trace:

```
2017-11-22 16:38:09.554 ERROR 8556 --- [           main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase   : Failed to load keystore type [PKCS12 ] with path [file:/C:/Users/dbush/workspace/my_app/target/classes/keystore.p12] due to [PKCS12  not found]

java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS12  not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:851) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:122) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:187) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:185) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:112) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:85) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:225) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:978) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:628) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:993) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:247) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:190) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at dbush.App.main(App.java:23) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PKCS12  KeyStore not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:848) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    ... 23 common frames omitted

2017-11-22 16:38:09.554 ERROR 8556 --- [           main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: Failed to load keystore type [PKCS12 ] with path [file:/C:/Users/dbush/workspace/myapp/target/classes/keystore.p12] due to [PKCS12  not found]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:114) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:85) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:978) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:628) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:993) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:247) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:190) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at dbush.App.main(App.java:23) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to load keystore type [PKCS12 ] with path [file:/C:/Users/dbush/workspace/myapp/target/classes/keystore.p12] due to [PKCS12  not found]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:187) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:112) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    ... 19 common frames omitted

2017-11-22 16:38:09.555 ERROR 8556 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:247) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:190) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at dbush.App.main(App.java:23) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1000) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: Failed to load keystore type [PKCS12 ] with path [file:/C:/Users/dbush/workspace/myapp/target/classes/keystore.p12] due to [PKCS12  not found]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:114) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:85) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:978) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:628) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:993) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to load keystore type [PKCS12 ] with path [file:/C:/Users/dbush/workspace/myapp/target/classes/keystore.p12] due to [PKCS12  not found]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:187) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:112) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Comment: @dur Java 8.  I did try setting `keystore.type.compat` but it had no effect.  I also tried using JKS files instead of PKCS12 files and got the same error.

Comment: So I came back to this and switched from PKCS12 back to JKS, and now it's working.  I'm not sure what did originally that caused a failure with JKS files.

Comment: I had the same problem when I pulled my project and set JDK to version 8. When I changed to JDK 11 the problem did not occur anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following properties in application.yml for enabling https

```
server:
  ssl:
    enabled: ${SSL_ENABLED:true}
    key-store: classpath:certificate.p12
    key-store-password: edgepay123
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-alias: 1
```

It seems you are missing the server.ssl.key-store-type property
Also use the following dependency of spring boot security

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

instead of the spring security dependency you are using

Comment: I actually did include the server.ssl.key-store-type property.  I missed that line when I copy/pasted the config.  I've edted to reflect.  Also, I did try org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security instead of org.springframework.security:spring-security-core but got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You added location to you keystore with this properties:server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
In spring boot classpath is src/main/resources folder. So put your keys in that folder like in the picture below.

[image]